# Autocomplète mobile phone

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I need to place a data search with autocomplète for a mobile website.

I try to use this code. It work fine on my web browser, but when I try on my mobile phone, the data list of autocomplète is no display.
Someone can tell me where I forgot something ?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body> 

    <form action='' method='post'>
        <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });             

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database name');

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['country'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: i would suggest looking into the code behide https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ which seams to be working on the Iphone.

Comment: Great !!! Thank you very much for your precious help. It work fine.